# Java: Cannot filter ArrayList using Java-Streams

Tags: java, arraylist, stream

**The error I am getting**

I am getting the error `"The method map(Function<? super Car,? extends R>) in the type Stream<Car> is not applicable for the arguments`

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to filter the `xx ArrayList` but I keep getting this error and I don not or cannot tell why. I am new to Java so this is probably an error I have made

**This is my code**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.*; 
import java.util.Arrays;


public class BusCar
{
    // timetable
    String time;
    int platform;
    
    ArrayList<Car> xx = new ArrayList<Car>();

    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    public BusCar(String depTime, int plat)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        depTime =  time;
        plat =  platform;
    }
    //filename A CSV file of Train records.

    public void addFromFile(String filename)
    {
        TrainReader reader = new TrainReader();
        xx.addAll(reader.getTrains(filename));
    }
    
    public void printBefore(String time)
    {
        // prints all trains which depart before the given time 
        // one train per line
       xx.stream().filter(i -> Integer.parseInt(i.departureTime) < Integer.parseInt(time)).map(i-> System.out.println(i),newline);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `.map(i-> System.out.println(i),newline)` suppose to do? It seems you need to use foreach instead of map.

Comment: That’s where my error is I am trying to print what I just filtered and then add a new line below it hence the new line variable

Comment: Even if that worked, you don't have a terminal operation to start the stream.

Comment: Please show me I don’t know how to do that

Comment: You can put the println statement in filter() ,map() means you convert type A to type B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want to do this.  Your `Car` class needs to properly override `toString()`

```
xx.stream().filter(i -> Integer.parseInt(i.departureTime) < 
   Integer.parseInt(time)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so so much !!!

Comment: You're most welcome.